# Wrangling Patient-Drug Administration Data By Outcome

Tags: r

I am hoping to get some help with this problem. I have a theoretical data frame including a list of drugs, administration dates, patients, and an outcome that is logical (headache_cured: true or false).  I am hoping to modify in order to generate a new column that counts the number of unique patients who are taking a specific drug (which should remain unique rows, e.g., one drug per row) who are either cured or not of their headache.

For example,

```
patient_id <- c("a","a","b","c","d","d","d")
drug <- c("tylenol", "tylenol", "tylenol", "advil", "aspirin", "aspirin", "motrin")
date <- c("1/1/2000", "1/2/2000", "1/3/2000", "1/4/2000", "1/5/2000", "1/6/2000", "1/7/2000")
headache_cured <- c(T,T,T,T,F,F,F)

df <- data.frame(patient_id,date,drug,headache_cured)
```

Output:

| patient_id | date | drug | headache_cured |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1/1/2000 | tylenol | TRUE |
| a | 1/2/2000 | tylenol | TRUE |
| b | 1/3/2000 | tylenol | TRUE |
| c | 1/4/2000 | advil | TRUE |
| d | 1/5/2000 | aspirin | FALSE |
| d | 1/6/2000 | aspirin | FALSE |
| d | 1/7/2000 | motrin | FALSE |

I would like to create a new data frame built like this:

| drug | n_patients_cured | n_patients_not_cured |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tylenol | 2 | 0 |
| aspirin | 0 | 2 |
| motrin | 0 | 1 |
| advil | 1 | 0 |

I am sure this is trivial for most here, but I would really appreciate any help with this problem.

I have tried using code such as this below to solve the problem but cannot seem to figure this one out and would greatly appreciate a helping hand to a novice R user. Thank you!

```
df %>%
mutate(n_patients_cured = ifelse(headache_cured == T, n_distinct(patient_id),0) %>%
mutate(n_patients_not_cured = ifelse(headache_cured == F, n_distinct(patient_id),0)
```

Comment: Consider `mutate` first then `groupby` on drug and `summarise` using `n_distinct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution.
Count by the rows by drug and headache cured then reshape the data to wide format. The initial `mutate` is meant to make the final column names agree with the expected output.

```r
patient_id <- c("a","a","b","c","d","d","d")
drug <- c("tylenol", "tylenol", "tylenol", "advil", "aspirin", "aspirin", "motrin")
date <- c("1/1/2000", "1/2/2000", "1/3/2000", "1/4/2000", "1/5/2000", "1/6/2000", "1/7/2000")
headache_cured <- c(T,T,T,T,F,F,F)

df <- data.frame(patient_id,date,drug,headache_cured)

suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
})

df %>%
  mutate(headache_cured = ifelse(headache_cured, "cured", "not_cured")) %>%
  count(drug, headache_cured) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = drug,
    names_from = headache_cured,
    names_glue = "n_patients_{headache_cured}",
    values_from = n,
    values_fill = 0L
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   drug    n_patients_cured n_patients_not_cured
#>   <chr>              <int>                <int>
#> 1 advil                  1                    0
#> 2 aspirin                0                    2
#> 3 motrin                 0                    1
#> 4 tylenol                3                    0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Rui. I am having an issue now with the real data I am working with in which the command throws this error: "Error in `pivot_wider_spec()`:
! Can't convert `fill` <integer> to <list>."   I suspect this may be due to having multiple rows where there are duplicates. For example if with the above case, we duplicated the first row for patient a in the data.frame. How can I handle this? Should I try to use summarize before running the pivot_wider function to remove redundancy?

Comment: @mpianko Can you post a data example reproducing the error?

Comment: I was able to solve it by adding ```ungroup()``` into the code early on. I think prior grouping was the source of the error. Once I did this, the code worked perfectly and generated the table as requested. Thank you for your help!